# Project Euler #3 - code not working

Tags: c#, algorithm

I am actually practicing on project euler to improve my skills in c# and for the problem #3 I wrote the I present below code but it does not work as it give me a wrong result. the problem link is 
[here](https://projecteuler.net/problem=3)

Can you tell me why?

```
using System;
using System.Linq;

namespace ConsoleApplication22
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            int[] rep = new int[35];
            int index = 0;
            long nb = 600851475143;
            int divider = 2;
            while (divider < nb / 2)
            {
                while (nb % divider == 0)
                {             
                    nb /= 2;
                    rep[index] = divider;
                    index += 1;
                }
                divider += 1;
            }
            Console.WriteLine("The annswer is : " + rep.Max());
            Console.Read();
        }
    }
```

Comment: Can you tell us what exactly doesn't work?

Comment: I have doubts that users here remember all project euler problems by numbers

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow, please take our [tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour) and our guidlines on [how to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and what is [on topic](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic). "code not working" is not a good way to describe an issue. We advise to mention what happens when you run the code, and why that is not correct or what did you expect instead. It will allow us to narrow the source of the issue more quickly and increase your chances in getting an answer. You can [edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/44241230/edit) your question.

Comment: Does your code work for the sample provided? That is easier to debug.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should be dividing by `divider`, not by `2`. Also, the first `while` should go to `nb`, since you are always making your `nb` smaller.

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    int[] rep = new int[35];
    int index = 0;
    long nb = 600851475143;
    int divider = 2;
    while (divider <= nb)
    {
        while (nb % divider == 0)
        {
            nb /= divider;
            rep[index] = divider;
            index += 1;
        }
        divider += 1;
    }
    Console.WriteLine("The answer is : " + rep.Max());
    Console.Read();
}
```

Comment: This solves some issues, but not all: the challenge is to find the highest *prime factor*, not the highest *divisor*

Comment: @HansKesting - Actually, since in the second `while` he divides all the way by the current divisor, the divisors will always be prime.